# How to transform 365 days to datetype and combine columns?

Tags: r, datetime

I have a dataframe with year column, day (1/365 days, not month specified), and hour in military format. I would like to know how to combine them to a vector of class `Date`.

```r
year /  day  / hour

2004  / 33  /  0845

2005  / 133  / 1300 

2005 /  180 /  1600
```

and I am trying to get one column of class `Date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first `paste` together the rows of the data.frame and then parse the character vector as a `Date` vector with `as.Date`:

```r
df <- data.frame(
    year = c("2004", "2005", "2005"),
    day = c("32", "133", "180"), 
    hour = c("0845", "1300", "1600"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df
#>   year day hour
#> 1 2004  32 0845
#> 2 2005 133 1300
#> 3 2005 180 1600

as.Date(apply(df, 1, paste, collapse = "/"), format = "%Y/%j/%H%M")
#> [1] "2004-02-01" "2005-05-13" "2005-06-29"
```

Here, `%Y` reads a 4-digit year, `%j` reads the day-of-year, `%H` reads decimal hours (24 hour) and `%M` reads decimal minutes.